# Unable to open Public IPv4 DNS in AWS EC2 - Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Spring boot project which I want to host on an AWS-EC2 instance. I was able to create its image using Git-hub, Jenkin and docker. I was also able to successfully pull and run this image in the Linux console of my AWS-EC2 instance.

According the tutorial I was following I should have been able to open the project now using the public IPv4 DNS but the response I got was that it refuse to connect.

I know that this usually has to do with Inbound rules so I added a rule to allow all traffic but it didn't help.

For anyone who wants to know:
Git-hub repository: https://github.com/SalahuddinShayan/telecom
Docker-Hub repository: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/salahuddinshayan/telecom
Command I used to run the image in AWS:

```
docker run -p8081:8081 --name final-app --link docker-mysql:mysql salahuddinshayan/telecom
```

Security Groups:[image]

Networking Details:
[image]

Here is the Error:[image]

I am completely stumped by it. Does anyone an idea on what to do to fix this?

Comment: Please show your security group rules and networking details of your EC2 instance.

Comment: @PawelKam, I add the security group rules and networking details as requested.

Comment: You are transmitting on port 8081. `http://3.110.29.193:8081/` works fine from the EC2 side. 404 status is raised, so this is a client side error, not a server side error.

Comment: You should not use allow all protocols. add ingress rules for the right port and protocol.

Comment: @PawelKam If it is a client side error, that means the problem is with my system not the EC2 instance, right? if so should I add a rule to my pc's firewall to fix it?

Comment: It means that no firewall is blocking traffic and a process (your app) was found that listens on IP:Port that you require. The problem is that the process it encountered (your app) is sending only a WhiteLabel Error Page, which is a generic Spring Boot error page that is displayed when no custom error page is present. So the issue is with the Spring app itself and not with EC2 or with connection. In other words: the traffic can reach your Spring app, but your Spring app has nothing to say in response.

Comment: @PawelKam Thanks man, what you said made it click, what I was doing was directly clicking on the open address option for public DNS and add :8081/home which is the path to my home, that resulted in an https request and the cause of the error but once I pasted the whole add in an new tab it worked like a charm. As it is a dummy project for the sole purpose of learning AWS hosting process it doesn't have a error page, sorry about that and thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your client is calling the right protocol, e.g. http vs https.

Comment: You were right man, what I was doing was directly clicking on the open address option for public DNS and add :8081/home which is the path to my home, that resulted in an https request and the cause of the error but once I pasted the whole add in an new tab it worked like a charm.

Comment: Was happy to help!  Please mark this answer as a solution to your question.  Thank you!

Comment: Hey sorry for unselecting you answer but the problem I was facing did not got solved it seems. when I tried to open the Public DNS the same way I did yesterday it giving me the same error, i.e. refuse to connect. I haven't change anything in the instance. Can you try to connect from your end check what's wrong? for your reference I have attached image of the error I am facing.

Comment: Are you sure the IP of the instance did not change?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that with the screen shot of the networking details I took earlier. The IP did not change.

Comment: Could you try to terminate and create the instance afresh and try the new public IP?

Comment: Hey, I don't know why or how, but the container on which my app was running had stopped. The container for the DB was running fine but the app had stopped. I want to know the reason so this doesn't happen again, if you have any idea please, let me know.

Comment: You may consider running your containers in ECS.  This will allow to configure AWS health checks (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_healthcheck) in addition to the Docker health checks.  You can also set up an agent in your container to send the logs to CloudWatch so that you can troubleshoot any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are transmitting on port 8081. `http://3.110.29.193:8081/` works fine from the EC2 side. [404 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) is raised, so this is a client side error, not a server side error.

It means that no firewall is blocking traffic and a process (your app) was found that listens on IP:Port that you require. The problem is that the process it encountered (your app) is sending only a [WhiteLabel Error Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.actuator.customize-whitelabel-error-page), which is a generic Spring Boot error page that is displayed when no custom error page is present. So the issue is with the Spring app itself and not with EC2 or with connection. In other words: the traffic can reach your Spring app, but your Spring app has nothing to say in response.

As a side note, after deploying your app I would advise to refine the inbound traffic rules to allow only the traffic you want. There is no need of allowing all traffic on all ports.

Comment: Hey sorry to disturb you again but the problem I was facing did not got solved it seems. when I tried to open the Public DNS the same way I did yesterday it giving me the same error, i.e. refuse to connect. I haven't change anything in the instance. Can you try to connect from your end check what's wrong? see if you are still able to reach the webapp. for your reference I have attached image of the error I am facing.

Comment: Something clearly have changed - the same telnet command that worked yesterday now gets me *'Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused'*. Please make sure that a) your app is still running and b) that no changes to the security group or NACL were made.

Comment: You were right, I don't know why or how, but the container on which my app was running had stopped. The container for the DB was running fine but the app had stopped. I want to know the reason so this doesn't happen again, if you have any idea please, let me know.

Comment: That is a separate issue, you should open a new question for it or search for "running docker containers on AWS".